# How to extract hashtags in URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, frontend, uri

```
www.app.com/home#tag_name
```

In React, how do I extract `tag_name` in the above URL? Is there are any built in functions to do that?

Comment: Yes, if you have a valid URL (yours is missing a schema), you can use something like `new URL(urlString).hash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help.
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/get+url+hashtag+javascript

window.location.hash = '#hash_value';

location.hash

Answer (score 0):

```
history.location.hash
```

The above worked